# Selecting Rows in Pandas based on Values not working

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, nan

I have data-frame `df_test.head()`

```
0           0      20.570           17.77       132.90       1326.0   
1           0      19.690           21.25       130.00       1203.0   
2           0      11.420           20.38        77.58        386.1   
3           1      20.290           14.34       135.10       1297.0
```

I need to select rows with `value=0`

I've done the following:

```
MT=df_test.diagnosis==0

MT.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 568 entries, 0 to 567
Data columns (total 1 columns):
(diagnosis,)    568 non-null bool
dtypes: bool(1)
memory usage: 648.0 bytes
```

---

```
MT.head()

    dia
0   True
1   True
2   True
3   True
4   True
```

But when I try to select rows based on MT it gives the following:

```
df_test[MT]


0   0.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
1   0.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2   0.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
3   0.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
4   0.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
5   0.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
6   0.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     ...     NaN     NaN
```

So it gives every thing as NAN.

Any help?

Comment: What indication do you have that this is not the correct result?

Comment: Beacuse the Data frames contains data as you sees row with index  0 0           0      20.570           17.77       132.90       1326.0 but when i search for it ti shows NAN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an issue somewhere with how you're constructing `MT` or with what `df_test.diagnosis` actually is.

Typically when you have a `DataFrame` and you apply some logic you will return a `pandas.Series`. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'user_id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
                   'val': [11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77]})

MT = df.user_id == 1
type(MT)
#pandas.core.series.Series
```

However in your case you're doing something that makes it into a `DataFrame` When you slice a `DataFrame` with `[]` the behavior is very different depending upon what you send it. If you send it a boolean `Series` then it returns all columns of the rows where the `Series` is `True`

```
df[MT]
#   user_id  val
#0        1   11
```

However, if you pass it a `DataFrame` within `[]` then it instead masks the `DataFrame` returning only the values in columns where the mask is `True` and replacing everything else with `NaN`.

```
MT_df = MT.to_frame()
type(MT_df)
#pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

df[MT_df]
#   user_id  val
#0      1.0  NaN
#1      NaN  NaN
#2      NaN  NaN
#3      NaN  NaN
#4      NaN  NaN
#5      NaN  NaN
#6      NaN  NaN
```

`MT_df` is has no column `val` so all entries become `NaN` and only has 1 `True` value within `user_id` so that value is passed. The rest are masked to `NaN`.

Ultimately, you need to figure out what is causing `MT` to become a `DataFrame`, but a sloppy fix would be to do `df[MT.values]`